# Where is GoogleService-info.plist stored in an ios app?

Tags: ios, firebase, plist

I have a Cordova app and it seems to cache the GoogleService-info.plist keys  i.e if i update the  app with the new GoogleService-info.plist keys it is still using the old one. But if i unisntall and then install the new build then the new keys are reflected.

IS there a way to programmatically clear old cached GoogleService-info.plist keys?

The steps that followed -

- Builded iOS app with **GoogleService-info.plist(project A)**.
- **Triggered** the notification from **Google cloud messaging (project A)** and got it in ios Device.
- Then builded ios app with a diff **GoogleService-info.plist(project B)**.
- **Updated** the app in iOS device.
- **Triggered** the notification from **Google cloud messaging (project B)** but never received the  notification ios Device.
- **Triggered** the notification from **Google cloud messaging (project A)** and got the notification. even if the app is builded with different key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fully rebuild and install the app in order for the contents of a new GoogleService-info.plist file to take effect.  There should be no need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem even on fully doing a rebuild and updating the app the new keys donot get reflected.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question to explain in step by step detail what you are doing so that anyone can reproduce the issue.